# Taking the bit of a file and displaying them

Tags: java, python, file, bit

I was wondering if it was possible to read a file bit meaning 0's and 1's and them displaying them, in either java or python. I don't know if it possible.

Comment: What is "*file bit*"? Please clarify.

Comment: how would i go about doing that, lets say i have a text file, in it has a paragraph, do i convert the file into a binary file, or convert the paragraph to bits, that's where I am lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to read bits from bytes while knowing the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the host system. That is, if you want an exact representation of the file.

```
import sys
sys.byteorder
open("fname").read(1)

if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN));
// Java reads and writes bytes pretty naturally, also.
```

You will need to use [bitmasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) to read the actual bits from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you read the file as byte stream (which you would typically do with a file), and then display the bytes in binary.